# Excel dollar sign text not being converted to a number

Tags: excel, formatting

When I input Euro or Sterling values into an excel sheet, they are automatically recognized as numbers/currency and right aligned and I can also extract their value.

e.g. £10 is automatically right aligned. Using the formula `=VALUE(A1)` returns 10 as it should. This also worked when using the € symbol. However if I used the $ symbol, the value is recognized as text and using the above formula results in `#VALUE!`. Maybe it has something to do with my Windows regional/language settings which are for UK not US.

EDIT: I have two entries under accounting formats:
£ English (U.K.)
$ English (U.S.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out a work around for anyone with a similar problem. I used `=VALUE(REPLACE(A1,1,1,""))` in order to remove the dollar sign and just get the value of the number, the number can then be formatted using the '$ English (U.S.)' accounting format.

Comment: +1: alternatively replace the $ with nothing (using ctrl+H) and your selected text values will be converted automatically to numeric values. In VBA you can just use `[A1]=[value(A1)]` since Standard US format is used by default.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively to @Matt 's answer, if your currency sign is not the first character or has a random position in the text, you can use `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"$","")`.

Answer (score 3):

`$` is used for fixed cell references - e.g. `$A$10`.  This is very useful when copying a formula or filling an entire column from it.  You should just format your cell as currency and set the formatting to display a dollar sign instead.

Comment: Upvote because you're right, but I posed the question badly. I don't enter the values myself, I receive excel sheets and would have to remove all the dollar signs first in order to use your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and sorry that my answer wasn't any help!  Good luck!

Comment: This would be the case if you were entering values with a formula, but we're talking about entering a value straight into the sheet, so this parsing doesn't come into play.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to use the replace command.
Highlight the cells, click on edit, then replace, type in $ and replace with +