# how to insert '$' sign in some columns having data type number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table:

```
CREATE TABLE Prod(
  PRODUCT  VARCHAR2(26 BYTE),
  CUSTOMER VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  QTR1 NUMBER(5,0),
  QTR2 NUMBER(5,0),
  QTR3 NUMBER(5,0),
  QTR4 NUMBER(5,0)
);
```

I want to insert '$' sign into column '**qtr1**','**qtr2**','**qtr3**','**qtr4**'.

Example: If 200, 400, 500 in column then after inserting it shows as $200,$400,$500.

Comment: `$` is not a number, so you can't insert it into a number

Comment: Insert into **which** column? Alas, "column" is ambiguous; it may mean column in the table (stored on disk), but it also means column in the output of a query. You should **not** think about inserting dollar sign in the table stored on disk. To add it to the output of a query, you can do it easily with the `TO_CHAR()` function.

Comment: @MT0 if I want to remove '$' sign from excel sheet then what should I do

Comment: Put the cursor just after the `$` symbol and press the delete key. Alternately you could search for ["excel remove currency symbol"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12260887/1509264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` with either `$` or `L` (with the `NLS_CURRENCY` set in either the session/database or as an explicit argument) in the format model:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( qtr1, '$99990' ) AS qtr1,
       TO_CHAR( qtr2, '$99990' ) AS qtr2,
       TO_CHAR( qtr3, 'L99990' ) AS qtr3,
       TO_CHAR( qtr4, 'L99990', 'NLS_CURRENCY=$' ) AS qtr4
FROM   PROD
```

Comment: if I want to remove '$' sign from column in excel sheet then what should I do